# The Push Notifications feature is not activated on the site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

All of a sudden I started to seeing below error with PnPPowershell.

> Get-PnPContentType : The Push Notifications feature is not activated
>   on the site

When I googled I got below article which suggests activating a certain feature. When I used Get-PnPFeature to see more about this feature I couldn't find it.

https://veenstra.me.uk/2016/01/27/office-365-the-push-notifications-feature-is-not-activated-on-the-site/

If this was working why all of a sudden it stopped?

Comment: I ve got such an error randomly. Then it disappeared without any manipulations in half an hour. Weird thing.

Comment: I think my post solves the solution, it would be nice if you could set it as "answer" so we get this question closed, thanks.

Comment: I don't know with you guys. But in my case, the issue was because I do Get-PnPWeb | Format-List. When I removed this specific code, the error back to normal without enabling the said feature in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a try/catch. In case of error, just add the feature if needed, and retry

```
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 41e1d4bf-b1a2-47f7-ab80-d5d6cbba3092
```

You need either to be connected to a site or provide a connection context by the *-Connection* param